# for loop in startcompass freezes

Tags: c++, for-loop

I have a compass/radar for my game, code below, and when I call the function startcompass it freezes and does nothing, Can someone help its only a 16-16 compass.

my problem is it doesn't show compass which is a char array

```
int startcompass()
{
cx = x;
cy = y;
for (int g_comp_y = 0; g_comp_y < showy; g_comp_y++)
{
    cy++;
    for (int g_comp_x = 0; g_comp_x < showx; g_comp_x++)
    {
        compass[g_comp_y][cx] = map1[g_comp_y][cx];
    }
}
while (g_compass = 1)
{
    for (int g_comp = 0; g_comp < showx; g_comp++)
    {
        cout << compass[g_comp] << endl;
    }
            system("pause>nul");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while (g_compass = 1)` -> `while (g_compass == 1)`

Comment: Not getting much use out of `g_comp_x`. Is this by design?

Comment: Enable warnings in your compiler settings. Then it would tell you about that.

Comment: I have warnings enabled

Comment: @grimreaper935 _"I have warnings enabled"_ `-Wall` of them?

Comment: You would benefit from finding out why you are not receiving typical warnings from your compiler.  We all make typos.  Your typos should certainly trigger warnings, though.

Comment: @grimreaper935 _"... it freezes ..."_ Sure it does. Consider that `g_compass = 1` **always** yields `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though your while loop is infinite. The variable g_compass isn't being modified anywhere inside the nested for loop.

EDIT:
It also seems that your compass is a 2D array: compass[g_comp_y][cx]

But the for loop that attempts to print it only uses 1D array: compass[g_comp]. You should make them the same.

Comment: @grimreaper935 edited my answer in regards to your edit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the value of g_compass in the loop, or it will never exit. As of now, it is an infinite loop.